# [ self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ]; doesn't work in delegate callback

Tags: ios

I have A -> B - >C controllers, linked with the next delegate:

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)onResult:(ControllerDelegateObject *)delegateObject;

@end
```

and in C I call:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ControllerDelegateObject *object = [[ControllerDelegateObject alloc]init];
    object.model = indexPath.row;
    [delegate onResult:object];
    [ self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
}
```

than I get in B:

```
-(void)onResult:(ControllerDelegateObject *)delegateObject{
    delegateObject.brand = self.chosenBrand;
    [delegate onResult:delegateObject];
    [ self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ]; **//doesn't work**
     NSLog(@"TEST2");
}
```

why [ self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ] is not called second time in the delegate callback?

Comment: Is `NSLog(@"TEST2")` being executed?

Comment: make sure delegate is not self. where do you initialize 'delegate' ?

Comment: Is NSLog(@"TEST2") being executed? - YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go to A:

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

Or another choice if you have more than 3 view controller A->B->C->D and you want to go from D to B.

```
- popToViewController:animated:
```

Refer to [UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)